# How to accept payments online for 3rd party users and charge a commission?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'd like to accept payments from the customers in behalf of 3rd party users and charge a commission for it. This is something similar to how the freelancer sites work, where clients pay workers and the site owner charges a commission.
I'm curious how such systems could be developed or what payment processing providers can help with it?

Any tips are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which country are you paying out in?

Answer (score 0):

If you are based in the `UK` then [Nochex](http://www.nochex.com) may be something that can help you.

Kind regards,
Peter